# Retraining gradient boosting classifier on its hits and misses

Tags: classification, class-imbalance, boosting

I have trained a gradient boosting model on historical data to predict whether person registers a business or not (binary classification problem). Right now the model is on the stage of online A/B-test. During this test we have collected some real examples when the model hits the right person or misses. There is incentive to add these examples into the training set and retrain the model to improve its performance (like in RL). The following difficulty arises:

1. it will be great to calculate classification quality metrics (AUC-ROC, AUC-PR, etc.) for refined model before the new online test
2. data is split time-wise to prevent data leak from future periods
3. there is a small number of new positive examples from test (about 200) and hundreds of thousands of negative examples
4. classification metrics calculated on small number of positive examples tend to be unstable, so it will be required to add all new examples to testing set for proper calculation of offline classification metrics as online test examples are most actual ones
5. thus, it will be impossible to test this new approach with model refinement on hits and misses offline as the training set won't include the new information. I will only be able to check the performance of the model during new online test where the model will be trained on all available data.

My question is the following: is the described procedure the only possible option in this situation? Does it make sense to calculate classification metrics on testing sample with small number of positive examples (i.e. take 100 positive examples from ongoing A/B test to check the model performance and add other 100 to extended training set)? Is there any other way to check the proposed approach or I should try some other modeling technique?